# Dependent picklists work in the browser but don't work in Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app, dependent-picklist

I have a series of dependent picklists on the Lead create page, with field dependencies set up on them. For the same user, these dependent picklists populate with the correct values based on the value chosen in the controlling field when I try it in the browser version of Salesforce, however the dependent picklists remain inactive after populating the controlling field with a value in the Salesforce1 application. The user's profile has Read & Create permissions on the Lead object and has access to all the fields in the layout. None of the fields in the layout are read-only.

Am I missing something here? I thought browser conditions are replicated as such in Salesforce1, but apparently not. Is there something else required to make this work?

**Update:** This is occurring on the standard Lead create page under the Leads tab in Salesforce1.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Salesforce1 [Unsupported Visualforce Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/vf_dev_best_practices_components_unsupported.htm). Specifically:

> `<apex:inputField>` for field types that use a widget for input, instead of a basic form field

I'm guessing that's what's driving your dependent picklists?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you enabled the page for SF1. There are certain components that aren't particularly compatible with SF1. I suggest you look at the Salesforce1 Mobile App Developer Guide, particularly the [Visualforce Guidelines and Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/vf_dev_best_practices.htm) section which covers Visualforce Components and Features to Avoid in Salesforce1 along with Unsupported Visualforce Components. It also makes suggestions for how to get optimal pages that will work well in both desktop and mobile environments.